# Is there a difference between "-iĝigi" kaj "-igi"?

Tags: affixes

For example, is the meaning of

> Mi kuraĝ**iĝig**as lin.

different from

> Mi kuraĝ**ig**as lin.

?

Answer (score 5):

For the most part, especially if the "root" is an adjective like *kuraĝa*, I would say they are interchangeable ("to cause to be courageous" vs "to cause to become courageous"). In that case I think just *igi* would be preferred stylistically.

In some situations, mostly when the "root" is a verb, there may be a *slight* difference in meaning which may or may not be important.

- *stari: Resti senmova vertikale sur la piedoj aŭ genuoj...*
- *stariĝi: Meti sin en vertikalan pozicion...*
- *starigi: Meti ion tiamaniere, ke ĝi staru...*

So I would understand that *starigi* implies that the subject is the one placing the object in a vertical position, while *stariĝigi* implies that the subject is somehow causing the object to place *itself* into a vertical position. *Araneo, kiu subite aperis apud li, stariĝigis lin* -> A spider that suddenly appeared next to him caused him to stand up. vs. *La viroj starigis sian ebrian amikon, ĉar li mem ne povis stariĝi* -> The men stood up their drunk friend because he couldn't stand up himself.

Comment: You correctly describe the difference between "-igi" and "-iĝigi" when added to a verb root. However, it should be pointed out that "-iĝigi" is very uncommon. Sometimes people abbreviate it to "-igi", when the context makes the intended meaning clear enough. But in general, it is preferable to say "igi ...-iĝi" in two words, when this special meaning is indeed intended. All this is described well in PMEG: http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj_frazroloj/ig.html#j-zos